# how to replace nan value using the value of which from other rows with common column value

Tags: pandas, merge, nan

Using column B as the reference how can I replace NaN value

```
>>> a
A   B  
1   1     
Nan 3     
1   1    
Nan 1
Nan 2      
5   3       
1   1    
2   2
```

I want result like this.

```
>> result 
A   B  
1   1     
5   3     
1   1    
1   1
2   2      
5   3       
1   1    
2   2
```

I tried merging on the column `b` but couldn't figure out
`b=a.groupby('B').reset_index()`
`dfM = pd.merge(a,b,on='B', how ='left')`

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html

Comment: @Riley Even tho I look at this doc I don't know which method to use it.. could you help me?

Comment: `a["A"].fillna(a["B"])`

Comment: @Riley I don't think it's the right way first Nan should be replaced to "5" by using 6th row

Comment: Ah ok, I see what you're doing now.  I assumed your first 5 was a typo.  So 1 in B, always means 1 in A.  And 3 in B, always means 5 in A etc?

Comment: yes! that correct! I feel like it'll be easy but can't figure out for 2 days...haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need a map from values in column `B` to the values in `A`.

```
mapping = a.dropna().drop_duplicates().set_index("B")["A"]
```

It looks like this

```
B
1    1.0
3    5.0
2    2.0
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Filling null values becomes irrelevant at this point.  We can just map `B` to get column `A`

```
a["B"].map(mapping)
```

This gives you

```
0    1.0
1    5.0
2    1.0
3    1.0
4    2.0
5    5.0
6    1.0
7    2.0
Name: B, dtype: float64
```

Cast to int and use it to overwrite column `A` in your original dataframe if you need to.

Comment: AWESOME!!!!!! Thank you so much...!!Have never no experience using mapping...!!